# VBScript exit code 3010 for SCCM 2012

Tags: vbscript, legacy, sccm

I am writing a vbscript to install a .exe application. Script works fine except that once the script is completed I need SCCM 2012 to get a exit code of 3010 so that it would schedule a restart of the PC.
The .exe when run with silent switch suppresses the reboot but the application won't work until restarted. Could you help with a vbscript to return 3010 once setup is finished.

Answer (score 0):

If your script runs under cscript.exe, use [WScript.Quit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw0fx1aw%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

```
copy con 27878706.vbs
WScript.Quit 3010
^Z
        1 file(s) copied.

cscript 27878706.vbs

echo %ERRORLEVEL%
3010
```

Comment: For SCCM to detect this I think it would probably work with wscript.exe just the same